# Create two sub-projects within one in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

I want to create a game project, and I need a server and a client for this.

I'm using Xcode 4.3, how can I create a projet `Game` which will contain two "sub-projects" :

- Client
- Server

I'd like to be able to build both independently. Is this kind of trick possible with xcode or shall I create two different projects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, it's called a workspace. Drag one of your projects onto the other and  you will be asked to make a workspace.

- Create a Server Project.
- Create a client Project.
- Drag the client project into the server project and drop it below. (or vice-versa)